# Exception Not Working

Tags: magento2, event-observer, exception, messages

I have an observer for sales_order_save_before

The custom message shows when the user is logged in, but throws the generic message if they are a guest. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: What is the expected behavior of the observer? Are you trying to get this to always trigger during checkout, before the order is placed? If so, I believe the event you would be looking for is "sales_order_*place*_before", not "sales_order_*save*_before".

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145403)

Comment: Changing the event solved the issue. Thank you!